# jsfiddle script works in jsfiddle but doesn't work in local when i try it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help. Found exactly what I need, a script in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/#run) that works in jsfiddle, but when i take exactly the same script, create an html with script, css file....it doesn't work.

Can someone try the scipt and tell me what's wrong? Thanks a lot!!!

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Comment: Do you also include jQuery2 on your local site? It's a dependency for that fiddle

Comment: And jsFiddle code is wrapped in onload handler, are you at least waiting for DOM to be fully parsed?

Comment: Found the problem....For newbies, like me, to use fiddle, just add /show at the end of the jfiddle link (example: http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/show/). Then, right click and inspect the source code. In my case, I forget at the first line $(window).load(function(){  and my jquery file was not working so i had to put <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>